# How can I prove or disprove this function is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> $$F (x ,y) = \frac {x|y|}{(x^2 + y ^2)^{0.5}}$$ when $xy \neq 0$
>   and $F(x,y) =0 $ elsewhere.
>
> How can I prove or disprove this function is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

My try :

I have used the concept of directional dervative. I got the direction derivative in the direction of $(a,b)$ ●[$ab \neq 0$]● is $\cfrac {a|b|}{(a^2 + b^2)^{0.5}}$ which can not be  written as a linear function of $a$ and $b$. So the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Am I right? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try plugging in $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and letting $r\to0$.

Comment: Can you please tell me if my try is correct?

Comment: That the function cannot be written as a linear function of $a$ and $b$ does not mean that the function is not differentiable. Differentiability has to do with whether a function can be nicely *approximated* by a linear function.

Comment: For example, we have $$\frac{x\,|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=r\cos(\theta)\,|\sin(\theta)|$$ If we look in the directions $\theta=\frac\pi4$ and $\theta=-\frac\pi4$, we get that the linear function would be $\frac1{\sqrt2}x$. However, looking in the direction $\theta=0$, this is in error by $\frac1{\sqrt2}x$, which is *not* $o(x)$. This means that this function cannot be nicely approximated by a linear function.

Comment: Can you please write an answer elaborately? I did not get you here.@robjohn

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $f=0$ on the axes, the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ both equal $0.$ If $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0),$ then we would have

$$f(x,y) = f(0,0) +0\cdot x + 0\cdot y +o[(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}]\,\,\text {as } (x,y)\to (0,0).$$

Is that true?

Comment: Can you pleass tell me what I have thought is true or not?@zhw

Comment: Can you pleass tell me what I have thought is true or not?@zhw.

Comment: Can you please point out where did I make mistake in my try?@zhw

Comment: Your approach is fine, as long as you can prove that the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ is not a linear function of $(a,b).$

Comment: $\cfrac {a|b|}{(a^2 + b^2)^{0.5}}$  - I think this can not be expressed as a linear function of $a$ and $b$. Am I right?@zhw

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of $f$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
&=\frac{\left(1,x^3/y^3-x/y\right)}{\sqrt{x^2/y^2+1}^3}
\end{align}
$$
Since the gradient of $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.